# Prevent renumbering after titlepage (which occurs at the start of an appendix)

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing an article class  document with several appendices. One of those appendices starts with a title page. After that titlepage, the number restarts.

How can I stop that from happening?

Comment: Are you using special packages we should be aware of? Could you provide a minimal code of your document starting with `\documentclass[..]{..}` and ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Either save the number before `\titlepage` and then reset it afterwards or don't use `\titlepage` just lay it out yourself.